# Python Kivy not loading ids from kv file, when calling function from another class

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, python-3.10

Im trying to interface with some BoxLayout elements in my .kv file, but the ID's arent loading when I call a function from the class in another class.

main.py file:

```
class FreeStyleScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FreeStyleScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.draw_card = FreeStyle().draw_card

class MainMenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TarotApp(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainMenuScreen(name='mainmenu'))
        sm.add_widget(FreeStyleScreen(name='freestyle'))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TarotApp().run()
```

freestyle.py file:

```
class FreeStyle(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FreeStyle, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.store = JsonStore('cards.json')
        self.cards = {'card1': 'Example Card'}

    def draw_card(self):
        self.card1.text = self.cards['card1']
```

tarotapp.kv:

```
ScreenManager:
    MainMenuScreen:
        name: 'mainmenu'
    FreeStyleScreen:
        name: 'freestyle'


<MainMenuScreen>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: "Main Menu"
        Button: 
            text: "Free Style"
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'freestyle'


<FreeStyleScreen>
    card1: card1

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            id: card1
            text: ""

    Button:
            text: "Draw Cards"
            on_release: root.draw_card()
```

But I keep getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'FreeStyle' object has no attribute 'card1'. Did you mean: 'cards'?
```

It works fine when I return a FreeStyle instance from the build function, but when I call the function from the FreeStyleScreen class, it doesn't load the ID. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the FreeStyle(BoxLayout) dosn't have any ids and don't need to the BoxLayout as it is a normal class better used for OOP(Object Oriented Proragamming)

FreeStyle class should look like this instead:

```
class FreeStyle:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FreeStyle, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.store = JsonStore('cards.json')
        self.cards = {'card1': 'Example Card'}

    def draw_card(self):
        return self.cards['card1']
```

and the way you have created your screenmanager you don't need the screemanager in the kv file:

```
<MainMenuScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: "Main Menu"
        Button: 
            text: "Free Style"
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'freestyle'


<FreeStyleScreen>
    card1: card1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            id: card1
            text: ""

        Button:
            text: "Draw Cards"
            on_release: root.draw_card()
```

if you wanna use screenmanager in the kv file you should return the kv file instead like this:

```
class TarotApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('test.kv')
```

Hope this helps